# Prove or disprove: If $X | U$ is independent of $Y | V$, then $E[XY|U,V] = E[X|U] \cdot E[Y|V]$.

Tags: conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

I may have missed something basic here. Suppose $U$ and $V$ are continuous random variables such that $E[X|U]$ and $E[Y|V]$  makes sense for some random variables $X$ and $Y$. If $X|U$ is independent of $Y|V$, does it follow that

$$
 E[XY|U,V] = E[X|U]\cdot E[Y|V]\ ?
$$

Any simpler explanation is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you state precisely what you mean by $X|U$ and $Y|V$ being independent? $X|U$ is not a random variable. You can talk about two random variables being independent when conditioned on a given sigma field, but you are conditioning on two different random variables. As far as I know such a concept does not exist.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I have a side question Kavi. ""Let U be a uniform random variable on (0, 1), and suppose that the conditional distribution of X, given that U = p, is binomial with parameters n and p"" Then is it acceptable to write $X|U = p \sim Binomial(n,p)$ therefore $X|U$ is a Binomial RV? Or does $X|U$ still not make sense? I know it can make sense to say that $E[X|U]$ is a RV.